# What is the purpose of having the IMF and CIA

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible

In Mission: Impossible – Rogue Nation, Brandt is seated along with the head of the CIA Alan Hunley, before an oversight committee. Brandt has to explain the IMFs actions and early on the IMF is disavowed, disbanded and it's activities absorbed into the CIA.

From this scene alone, we can establish that the IMF has a little more freedom to do what it wants, but it still answers to an oversight committee, and to a larger extent, The President.

The President can even disavow them which happens twice as far as I know in the movies. This means, they aren't acting without government knowledge and unknowing to everyone else. The President, oversight committee, and those close enough or with a security clearance high enough, will know.

Why not give the CIA a little more freedom, and allow the Special Activities Division to do what the IMF does? Why create another agency similar to the CIA, that essentially gathers intelligence, analyzes it, and acts on it?

Or to keep MI fans happy, dissolve the CIA and let the IMF take over.

Comment: For me this was a massive side step to the purpose of the IMF.  IMF is supposed to be totally secret - no oversight committees, nothing.  The idea is that they can do things that would otherwise be illegal - if they're caught, the govt denies everything.  Lumping them together with the CIA in that film completely strips that idea, and makes them just another dept.

Comment: ... also the film series is based on a 1966–1973 tv series.

Comment: @Tim - Exactly! What they should have done in the movies was dissolve the CIA and replace it with the IMF without oversight. Remember it's a fictional movie not a documentary so them dissolving the CIA is not implausible.

Comment: @Tim - It's bad writing because in the trivia section on IMDb, it states that while in production for this and the last movie, they didn't really have a script, and only outlined the action scenes.

Comment: Basically what IMF's list of actions is rather different than of CIA. IMF is made to be a secret black ops type organization. Being IMF means if you fail in on a mission, you'' be left behind and nobody will come for you and government will deny any knowledge on your action. While being CIA, you can't do what IMF could do. you've to play by the book.

Comment: @Vishwa - Both organizations have black ops teams or conduct black ops, and both have a rule leaving you behind if your caught. Why not give the CIA a little  more freedom and let them do what IMF does, simply put the IMF doesn't need to exist.

Comment: @QueenSvetlana CIA is a publicly known agency, while they do some black ops, CIA has to work under some limitations. and they have to always cover up their black ops and make them non-existent, so creating a separate division and push all the dirty work to them is easier,  I think

Comment: IMF is a known agency, to the government, the villians, and maybe even some members of the public(family members of agents). The can try to keep IMF a secret like the did in the 50s-60s with the CIA, but eventually the government had to acknowledge them. if the CIA has limitations then why not remove them? Or in the movie universe, as I said dissolve the CIA and let the IMF replace it.

Comment: If the IMF is a completely unknown secret agency and the CIA is only a *mostly secret* agency, then dissolving the CIA would beg the question in the public eye **"who's going to cover the bases the CIA was covering?"**  If there's no explanation, people will be left feeling like the American government up and abandoned a relatively important branch of their national security.  The only way to absolve that would be to reveal the existence of the IMF, which defeats the benefits claimed re: secrecy.

Comment: @Steve-O - Good point, but why have two? If anything, why not just dissolve the IMF and keep the CIA? As I pointed out, both agencies operate the same and have to sit before an oversight committee. If IMF were a private agency then it's different but having a direct link to the president(enough to be disavowed) means they aren't. Unless, and maybe I'm spending too much time on this, but IMF could have a contract with the U.S government that states they will be left alone as long as they don't disrupt U.S relationships, which clearly happened in the last two films.

Comment: The US has weak central government and allows the creation of new natsec groups willy-nilly .

Comment: @Neuromancer - I guess. I'm reading too much into what should be a fun action movie. I'm just saying that the plot shows there wasn't enough thought into the details of the story but you could also say I'm blowing a small problem out proportion.  I didn't watch the TV show or the first movie, but was the IMF created by the government?